# How can I access feedly API

Tags: api, rest, rss, feedly

I have gone through the developer site:

http://developer.feedly.com/

In the authentication API, one the input is `client_id`

> client_id string Indicates the client that is making the request. The
>   value passed in this parameter must exactly match the value set during
>   the partnership program.

But, I do not see where can I get the client_id nor anything about the partnership program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page says:

> Once you sign-up for Feedly Cloud Developer Program, you will receive
>   a client id and client secret you can use to authenticate to the
>   sandbox.

I assume they will send you the id via email?

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that

Comment: Do I need to send a email or click a button so they can send me a ID and token by email?